# use Margin In Media Query Css

Tags: css, media-queries

I am Using Media Query In My Web Application For Width And Margins

```
    @media (max-width:1050px) {
    .row-fluid .span3 {
        width: 42%;

    }

    .row-fluid .span3 
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:1050px) {
    .span3 {
        width: 220%;
    }

    .span3 {
        width: 220%;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 1050px)
    {
     .row-fluid   .span3 {

               margin-left:35%;
            }

   .row-fluid .span3 {
                margin-left:35%;
            }
        }

        @media(max-width: 1050px)
    {
        .span3 {

                width: 320%;
            }

    .span3 {
                width: 320%;
            }
        }
```

It Is Working Fine With Width But Margin-Left Is Not Working And Guys I Don't Have Much Idea About Media Query That's Why My Code May Not Be Much Accurate.

Comment: show us your HTML?

Comment: this is bad CSS!!!

try it:

`@media(max-width:1050px) {
    .span3 {
        width: 220%;
    }
  
    .row-fluid  .span3 {
       margin-left:35%;
     }
}`

Comment: Yes I know The Code Is Full Of Bad Css's @ElenaSemenchenko But The Problem Is I Am Unable Tu Use Margin In Media Query

Comment: What's with the capital letter on every word? makes things hard to read

Comment: actually it is now my habit of using first letter capital @Pete